# leaflet control geojson layers by zoom level

Tags: zooming, leaflet, geojson

just looking for a way to control geojson layers by zoomlevel like minZoom , maxZoom for tileLayers, any ideas?

Descrition: geojson points layer, different classes of points, say Nation capitol, Province Capitol, Department, capitol, rest of simple towns. 
Goal: at zoom level 4 display only Nation capitol (one only piont)
at zoom level 6 diplay all of 24 province capitols (you will only see a part of them)
at zoom level 8 display 524 departments capitols (you will only see a part of them)
at zoom level 10 display rest of towns, same idea.

thanks in advance.
JC

Answer (score 2):

Check out [Map events in the Leaflet Docs](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-events).

You can subscribe to the 'zoomend' event as well as 'zoomstart' and a few others

```
map.on('zoomend', function (e) {
    myZoomHandler();
});
```

In your zoom handler function, loop over your layers and add or remove layers as needed.

```
function myZoomHandler() {
    var currentZoom = map.getZoom();
    switch (currentZoom) {
        case 4:
         //show Capitols
        break;
        case 6:
         //show Provinces
        break;
        default:
         // etc
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Leaflet has a `viewereset` event that is triggered when the map updates (on load, on zoom).
You can do something like:

```
map.on('viewreset', function() {
   var zoom = this.getZoom();
   // show/hide layers based on zoom level
}, map);
```

One way to show/hide layers is through L.GeoJSON's `setStyle()` method (use `display` or `visibility` properties).

Comment: This is either wrong or out of date. You can do this, but you need to use the opacity property - display and visibility are not valid properties